# high Contrast mode using JQuery not working...Not sure why?

Tags: jquery

I got this code from a website saying that it would solve my problem but i cannot seem to get it to work. What am i doing wrong? I am trying to have the end-user click this button to display a High Contrast Mode of my website

```
<link rel="stylesheet" class="contrast-settings" href="http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css"/>
```

contrast.js

```
// Contrast changing script
$(".change-contrast").click(function () {
    var currentContrast = get_cookie('Contrast');
    if (currentContrast == "http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css" || currentContrast == "http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css") {
        $('.contrast-settings').attr("href", "http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/high-contrast.css");
        set_cookie('Contrast', 'http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/high-contrast.css', 1);
        } 
    else {
        $('.contrast-settings').attr("href", "/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css");
        set_cookie('Contrast', '/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css',1);
    }
    return false;
});
```

my html code is

```
<span class="change-contrast"><a href="#">Contrast</a></span>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? This JS references a `.contrast-settings` element that should be a `<link>` - does that exist?

Comment: I see you updated the question - where is `.contrast-settings` in your HTML?

Comment: I can't access either of the CSS files: http://cdn.zendaserarch.com/vampnerdlord.com/high-contrast.css - Is that part of the issue, or are they not public?

Comment: sorry was supposed to be zendasearch.com

Comment: I see a problem in your `if` logic - you're setting the cookie to `/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css` but checking if it's `http://cdn.zendasearch.com/vampnerdlord.com/main.min.css`. Those two strings will never match, so the `if` will always choose the `else`. It doesn't matter that the former is a relative path of the same URL, since you're just comparing strings.

Comment: no matter what i do it still doesnt work

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work," please?  Are there any error messages? Do the `get_cookie()` and `set_cookie()` functions exist?